# Adding focus inside dialog for accessibilty

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I have a dialog in my aurelia app that when I click the link to have the dialog appear, the focus goes back to the top of the page.
I have given it role="dialog" aria-labelledby="aboutHeader" aria-describedby="versionNumber" but the screen reader does not recognize the dialog. How can I put a keyboard focus on the dialog so that when I click "About" the next tab on my voiceover is inside the dialog, and on closing the dialog how do I get it back to the last focus of the "About" link?

```
<ux-dialog role="dialog" aria-labelledby="aboutHeader" aria-describedby="versionNumber">
      <ux-dialog-header><h2 id="aboutHeader">Header</h2></ux-dialog-header>

    <ux-dialog-body style="max-width: 750px;">
        <p id="versionNumber">Version Number</p>
        <p>Copyright Info Here</p>
    </ux-dialog-body>

    <ux-dialog-footer>
      <button click.trigger="controller.close()">Close</button>
    </ux-dialog-footer>
  </ux-dialog>
```

Comment: How is the focus managed, are you trying to do this with a hyperlink pointing to the modal H2? If you are then is the modal `display: none` until you click that link and if so is the feature built in for that or have you written some JS to open the modal youself? can you put a fiddle put together as I (and I am sure many others) am not be familiar with aurelia. This is very likely going to be a timing issue where you are trying to move focus to the heading before it is visible in the DOM but that is just a best guess based on what you have put in your question.

Comment: I second this, I don't know aurelia either. But ultimately you should have something like `myux-dialog.focus()` somewhere. Ideally, focus goes back to the trigger that opened the dialogue when it closes, so before focussing the dialogue, you'd  store a pointer to that trigger as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the feedback, it was helpful.
For this particular instance, I was able to add a ref="aboutButton" attribute to the h2 element and inside my ViewModel I added this.aboutHeader.focus() inside the attached() component lifecycle which is invoked once the component is attached to the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

This is something you can do once the modal is opened:

For the h2, add a tabindex=0 so that it can be focussed.

```
<ux-dialog-header>
  <h2 id="aboutHeader" tabindex="0">
      Header
  </h2>
</ux-dialog-header>
```

Now in your javascript or typescript file whatever you are using, add this logic:

```
const header = document.querySelector('h2#aboutHeader');

if (header) {
  let modifiedHeader: HTMLElement = header as HTMLElement;
  modifiedHeader.focus();
}

// The IF condition will make sure that if its not defined, or not present, it wont throw an console error for you
```

Now finally in the CSS file, add this:

```
// Set the border for the focus items
[tabindex]:focus {
  outline: 1px dashed gray;
  &[disabled] {
    outline: none;
  }
}

// For all the focusable items, this is how you can set the border so that you can see.
```

By doing all the above, the focus will go into the h2 tag and since its in the modal, the `role="dialog"` will work and it will resolve your issue.